# split two elements in a sub array in a new array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, split

I have an array that looks like:

```
my_array = 'limit: 1001: [1,2], 1002:[2,5], 1003:[1,2],1010:[1,3]
```

But I want to split my array like this:

```
[1001,1], [1001,2], [1002,2], [1002,5], [1003,1], [1003,2]....
```

is it possible in Python?

I've tried this:

```
[[[c for c in v.split(':')][0],a.split('(')[0]] for v in my_array.replace(' ','').split('limit:')[1].replace('),',';').replace('[','').replace('),',';').split(',') for a in [c for c in v.split(':')][1].split(';')]
```

Comment: You tried this, but ...?

Comment: It looks like this is possible. I would try splitting this into several simpler steps instead of putting everything into one giant expression.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the structure of the string is dict-like, using [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) seems much more straight-forward:

```py
import ast

my_array = 'limit: 1001: [1,2], 1002:[2,5], 1003:[1,2],1010:[1,3]'
my_array = '{' + my_array[6:] + '}'
my_dict = ast.literal_eval(my_array)

arr = [[key, i] for key, item in my_dict.items() for i in item]

print(arr)
```

Output:

```py
[[1001, 1], [1001, 2], [1002, 2], [1002, 5], [1003, 1], [1003, 2], [1010, 1], [1010, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse this yourself, I would suggest breaking the process in small steps:

```
my_array = 'limit: 1001: [1,2], 1002:[2,5], 1003:[1,2],1010:[1,3]'

parts      = [*map(str.strip,my_array.split(":")[1:])]  
leftParts  = [ part.rsplit(",")[-1] for part in parts[:-1]]
rightParts = [ part.split("]")[0][1:].split(",") for part in parts[1:]]
result     = [ [L,R] for L,Rs in zip(map(int,leftParts),rightParts)
                     for R in map(int,Rs) ] 
                     
[[1001, 1], [1001, 2], [1002, 2], [1002, 5], [1003, 1], [1003, 2], 
 [1010, 1], [1010, 3]]
```

- `parts` separates the string on ":" because it is the only separator that is not ambiguous (as opposed to commas).  You get substrings that combine consecutive but unrelated right and left parts.  while doing this, we skip over the 'limits' keyword and eliminate leading/trailing blanks to simplify the next steps.
- `leftParts` extracts the numbers before the ":".  These are now at the end of each part and preceded by a comma (or alone in the case of the first one). So we use rsplit to get the substring after last comma.  The last part in `parts` will never contain a leftPart because it is not followed by a new entry (so we only process parts[:-1] for this)
- `rightParts` extracts the bracket enclosed lists.  It first splits on the closing bracket and selects the substring preceding it (index 0).  The opening bracket is skipped and the enclosed list is split on commas. The first part in `parts` only contains a left side value so we skip it (i.e. only processing parts[1:] for this)
- We now have a list of left side strings (`leftParts`) and a list of right side lists (`rightParts`)
- The result is built by pairing up the left and right parts using zip() with a nested comprehension to combine each left-side value with all the corresponding right side values.  Conversion from string to integer is also preformed in this step

Using regular expression could simplify the parsing process and allow for easier handling of variations in the input (extra space, extraneous keyword, ...) :

```
import re

leftParts  = map(int,re.findall(r"\d+(?=:)",my_array))
rightParts = re.findall(r"(?<=\[)[\d\,]*(?=])",my_array)
rightLists = ( map(int,p.split(",")) for p in rightParts )
result     = [ [L,R] for L,Rs in zip(leftParts,rightLists) for R in Rs ] 

[[1001, 1], [1001, 2], [1002, 2], [1002, 5], [1003, 1], [1003, 2], 
 [1010, 1], [1010, 3]]
```

- `leftParts` is extracted directly by looking for a series of digits preceding a colon and converts them directly to integers
- `rightParts` extracts substrings enclosed in brackets.
- `rightList` easily splits the right parts and converts them to series of integers
- The result is produced the same way as before using values already converted to integers